# Translate messages in Django

Tags: python, django, translate

Using django 3.1.7 and Python 3.9, I'm trying to translate messages like this:

views.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
messages.success(request, _("File successfully uploaded"))
```

template.html

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
        <span style="list-style-type:none;">  {% trans message %} </span>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I, of course, have .po and .mo files build. Translations are working fine in other context. But in that particular case, I got this error message:

> AttributeError
> 'Message' object has no attribute 'replace'

I am not quite sure to understand...

Comment: if you are marking the translation string in the backend, you dont need to use the "trans" block in the html. Also, I think you need gettext_lazy instead of ugettext.

Comment: tried with gettext_lazy to. String is not translated.

Answer (score 0):

Use `translate` with variable instead of `trans`.